# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero - finding factors

Tags: java, factorization

this method takes in an int - however I keep getting an error message, does anyone know why?

```
 //finds the factors of a number that was entered
public void findFactors(int t)
{
    System.out.println("factors of " +t+ " are:");

    for(int i =0; i<t+1; i++)
    {
        if(t%i == 0)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that t%i is undefined when i is 0, as you can't divide by zero nor find the remainder.

Instead of starting your loop from 0, you should start from 1.

Change

```
for(int i =0; i<t+1; i++)
```

to

```
for(int i =1; i<t+1; i++)
```

(You could also consider starting testing from 2, as 1 will be a factor for all integers)